# CardView is causing app to crash (shown in the picture)

Tags: java, android, crash, cardview

I keep getting crashed everytime i run the code, i tried to remove the CardView codes and it's not crashed anymore. Can u help me guys, since im new to this environment and currently im working on a project, am i doing it wrong with the cardView codes?. Thanks

[crashed app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eu0x.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapps"
    tools:context=".utama">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardCam"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardPupuk"
                android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@+id/soilIv"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#989595"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/camIv"
                    android:layout_width="71dp"
                    android:layout_height="71dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/cam" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: will you please let know the errors , you will get them in the logcat at the bottom of android studio , also i would like to know why are you using a constraint layout if you are providing any constraints to it's directs children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`android:layout_marginEnd`**

> Specifies extra space on the end side of this view. This space is
>   outside this view's bounds. Margin values should be positive.

You should use proper value in **`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`** section.

**Don't**

```
 android:layout_marginEnd="@+id/soilIv"
```

It should be

```
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you it workedddddd. I hope you have a good day mate. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ranss Welcome. Move ahead.